# Error in wso2 proxy service

Tags: google-sheets, wso2, google-sheets-api, wso2-esb

I have the following proxy servicethat uses google spreadsheet connector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="googleTest" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" statistics="disable">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
      <googlespreadsheet.updateCells configKey="access">
        <key>14sCud5RqFt7O44Ol_GnTBgwFbZSnWAW-dJ833ryfWY8</key>
        <worksheetId>1</worksheetId>
        <cellId>R2C6</cellId>
        <inputValue>Inc</inputValue>
        <row>2</row>
        <col>6</col>
        <cellVersion>1dzdhc</cellVersion>
      </googlespreadsheet.updateCells>
      <log level="full"/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

However I run this proxy I get the following error:

```
[2015-11-26 19:15:04,506] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
```

How can I resolve this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're having is the following:

> Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'

This looks like it is an issue with the contentType. Is seems like you're sending JSON data (starting with `[`), but the output formatter expects XML (starting with `<`).

Add the following property to specify that you're sending json data:

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does not help

Comment: Please provide the complete proxy code and error log. Does it happend when you call the proxy or when sending out to google?

Comment: Hi I edited the code to include complete proxy service

Comment: It happens when I run the proxy using soap UI